# Heroku Ruby on Rails existing app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails application already created, I also created an application in heroku and I have git syncing automatically to deploy to heroku.

However when I run 'heroku open --app ' it only shows the default heroku page.

What can I do to make my application show on the browser?

Comment: Could you please paste the result for `git remote -v`

Comment: run this command to view log: `heroku logs -t`

Answer (score 0):

Did your app linked to heroku app? just check it with git remote it should show heroku git repo as remote. if not link it by heroku git add "git repo URL" (you can add this from UI as well) also mke sure that you pushed your code to heroku repo (like this git push heroku "branch") if everything is fine try with restarting the server by heroku restart

[this page](http://ruten.ca/2012/02/15/heroku-cheatsheet-useful-heroku-commands-reference/) may help you to learn heroku commands

Comment: Is there any tutorial you know about that tells you how to make an existing app to run on heroku?

Comment: not sure but this(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) may help you. One thing is sure to deploy app on heroku you need git repo. (and basic git knowledge